# How to resolve Could not find artifact org.eclipse.rcptt.extensions.ecl:parent:pom:2.3.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-rcptt

Getting compilation error as

> Non-resolvable parent POM for org.eclipse.rcptt.extensions.ecl:org.eclipse.rcptt.extensions.ecl.model:2.3.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact
> org.eclipse.rcptt.extensions.ecl:parent:pom:2.3.0-SNAPSHOT

I am using pom.xml as follows

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.rcptt.extensions.ecl</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>org.eclipse.rcptt.extensions.ecl</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.rcptt.extensions.ecl.model</artifactId>
<version>2.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
```

Comment: Your parent pom.xml is being found by Maven? Looks like the problem is that parent pom.xml cannot be found, maybe is your relativePath.

Comment: @LucianoBrum No not able to found.

Comment: Well, I think the problem is related with the parent pom location.